# $ is not defined Chrome Moblie

Tags: jquery

it's my first time here. I have a problem with Jquery is that when testing my site in Moblie Chrome the console informs that $ is not defined, I do not know what happened because in another browser moblie Via Browser worked correctly.
My HTML code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eruda"></script>
    <script>eruda.init();</script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <!--Font Awesome-->
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"-->
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
Body
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js" ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

scripts.js

```
var file_text = [];
var loadText;
var nome_arquivo = "";
var file_traduzido = [];
var file_so_texto = [];
var array_position = 0;
var file_positions = [];
var file_so_texto_traduzido = [];
var texto_final = "";

$(document).ready(function(){//error line

continue...
```

Comment: Just a quick guess here, but have you tried using https instead of http for the jquery script tag src?

Comment: have you tried moving your Jquery file just above your scripts file?

Comment: @DougF Thank you very much. After I tried here I saw that this was the mistake. Thank you very much and kiss Brazil.

Comment: @crazymatt Yes, but the problem has already been solved I thank the suggestion.

Comment: Glad to help.  :)